# Choose the comments element for the selected node in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am doing a blog which using the XML file. I want to display the comments for selected Post with ListView. Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
<Toy>
<ID>1</ID>
<Type>Despicable Me</Type>
<Character>Agnes Gru</Character>
<Description>Agnes, like her sisters, wished to be adopted by someone who cared about her.
At first, Agnes is only one out of the three sisters to be excited to be adopted by Gru. 
 She happily hugs his leg and plays games with him, whereas her sisters are gawping at  
 Gru, their dream of the 'perfect parents' in tatters. 
She is unaware of Gru's own dislike of the whole adoption, her innocence prevailing. 
She is a very naive and innocent child, which is why Margo is so protective of her. 
She thinks Gru's dog is cute and chases after him, despite some protest from Margo.
  </Description>
<Picture>agnes.jpg</Picture>
 <Comments>
  <Comment>
    It's a very cute little girl!
  </Comment>
  <Comment>
    It's a very cute little girl!
  </Comment>
</Comments>
 </Toy>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
<NewDataSet>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </NewDataSet>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Toy/Comments">
 <Toy>
  <Comments>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Comments>
 </Toy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my code behind:
(I had successfully passed the Session)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String ID = Session["ID"].ToString(); 
XmlDataSource2.XPath = String.Format("/NewDataSet/Toy[@ID='{0}']/Comments",ID);
}
```

I think something wrong with my code behind. Can anyone please assist me? 
Thank You.

Comment: You think something is wrong?  What do you think is wrong?  What output do you want? What output are you getting?  Without more information, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - ID is an element but in your XPath you treat it as attribute (@ID). Try to change `/NewDataSet/Toy[@ID='{0}']/Comments` into `/NewDataSet/Toy[ID='{0}']/Comments`.

Edit: this is result of your transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><NewDataSet>1Despicable MeAgnes GruAgnes, like her sisters, wished to be adopted by someone who cared about her.
At first, Agnes is only one out of the three sisters to be excited to be adopted by Gru. 
 She happily hugs his leg and plays games with him, whereas her sisters are gawping at  
 Gru, their dream of the 'perfect parents' in tatters. 
She is unaware of Gru's own dislike of the whole adoption, her innocence prevailing. 
She is a very naive and innocent child, which is why Margo is so protective of her. 
She thinks Gru's dog is cute and chases after him, despite some protest from Margo.
  agnes.jpg<Toy><Comments Comment="&#xA;    It's a very cute little girl!&#xA;  "/></Toy></NewDataSet>
```

As you can see you lost almost all your markup. Also ID element has gone so your xpath cannot return any data - just because there is no Toy element with element ID.

I don't know what exactly you want to do with your xslt - you should state it in more details.

But I don't understand why you need to transform your input xml. IMO the xpath `/NewDataSet/Toy[ID=1]/Comments/Comment` applied on original document should make the work.

Comment: i changed it, but it show nothing also. is it some problem with my xsl file?

Comment: I improved my answer - look at that. If it won't meet your needs you should provide more information about what are you trying to do.